# seleccionar mes 1 enero y el mes anterior sql

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, sqlite3

estoy trabajando con django y tengo el siguiente query que selecciona el mes anteior y el que elige el usuario
las columanas estan de esta manera

1. **datem** es el numero del mes el formato es char
2. **datey** es el numero en años el formato es char

es que en el documento la fecha viene **202201**
y lo almacene como año y mes en la base de datos
para que a la hora de mostrarlo puedes elegir año y mes de unos select

mi query seria

```
where ( client.id = %s and dbserver.dbname = %s )
and datey = %s and datem in(%s,%s) order by datem;
```

ahora bien el problema que me topo con esta query es a la hora de seleccionar el mes 1
ya que el anterior es el 12 pero del año ya no es igual y si intento colocar el año
como lo venia haciendo tambien me trae los registros del mes uno de año pasado
y ante todo muchas gracias por la ayuda.

resultado esperado:

```
datem | datey
01    | 2022
12    | 2021
```

saludos

P.D. si tienen alguna sugerencia tambien seria bien resibida

Comment: Puedes colocar el output actual y el esperado?

Comment: es sqlite? en que formato tenes las fechas? porque hay funciones minimas para transformar las fechas, y tranquilamente podrias transformala al mes que queres...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes comparar por tuplas `(mes,año)`, donde la tupla para el mes anterior la compones con la lógica correspondiente.

```
SELECT tabla.*
  FROM tabla
    JOIN (SELECT 1 m, 2022 a) v
  WHERE (datem,datey) = (m,a)
     OR (datem,datey) = ( CASE m
                            WHEN 1 THEN 12
                            ELSE m-1
                          END
                        , CASE m
                            WHEN 1 THEN a-1
                            ELSE a
                          END
                        );
```

El JOIN con `v` es únicamente para no repetir varias veces el marcador de posición de tus parámetros.

Comment: muchisimas gracias quedo exelente!